# Define component schema with drf-spectacular for django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-spectacular

I am using drf-spectacular to generate an OpenAPI schema for django. As I am not using serializers, I am defining everything in the `extend_schema` decorator. Now my question is, if it is possible to manually define a component schema.

Here is an example what my api view looks like:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from drf_spectacular.utils import (extend_schema, OpenApiExample)
from drf_spectacular.types import OpenApiTypes
from rest_framework.response import Response

@extend_schema(
    examples=[OpenApiExample(
        value=[
            {'title': 'A title'},
            {'title': 'Another title'},
        ],
    )],
    responses={
       200: OpenApiTypes.OBJECT
    }
)
@api_view(['GET'])
def list_articles(request):
    return Response([{'title': 'Test1'}, {'title': 'Test2'}])
```

and the corresponding component is shown as empty (e.g. in swagger):

[image: swagger-ui example of empty component]

[Here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) is the definition in the documentation but I cannot figure out how to achieve it with drf-spectacular.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OpenApiTypes.OBJECT` means that the response object can have any amount of fields. Of course Swagger UI cannot know those fields in advance and thus it shows `{}`, which may be unintuitive but it is correct.

What you want is to give your response some structure. Everything in spectacular revolves around serializers/components. If you don't want to have explicit serializers, you can create implicit ones with [inline_serializer](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.inline_serializer)

```py
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema, OpenApiExample, inline_serializer

@extend_schema(
    examples=[OpenApiExample(
        value=[
            {'title': 'A title'},
            {'title': 'Another title'},
        ],
    )],
    responses={
       200: inline_serializer(
           name='Article',
           fields={
               'title': serializers.CharField(),
           }
       )
    }
)
@api_view(['GET'])
def list_articles(request):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not expect an answer any more after a month

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to use simple dictionary instead of `inline_serializer`:

```py
@extend_schema(
    ...
    responses={
        (200, 'text/html'): {
            'description': 'Simple HTML page',
            'type': 'string',
            'example': '<html>Example text</html>'
        },
        (202, 'application/json'): {
            'description': 'JSON response',
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'title': {
                    'type': 'string',
                    'minLength': 1,
                    'maxLength': 128
                }
            },
            'required': [
                'title'
            ]
        },
    }
)
...
```